# source.cpp:LINE:COL: error: function definition is not allowed here

Tags: c++, c

I am a beginner in c++ and I am trying to make a chess game I is not finished yet. When I try to compile the code below it gives me 
error: function definition is not allowed here. for isValidMove, movePiece, and Main
Can anyone tell me why it gives me that.

The code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

char board[8][8] = {
'R','N','B','Q','K','B','N','R',
'P','P','P','P','P','P','P','P',
'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',
'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',
'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',
'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-',
'p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p',
'r','n','b','q','k','b','n','r'};

void swap(char board[8][8], int inRow, int inCol, int outRow, int outCol) {
    char tmp = board[inRow][inCol];
    board[inRow][inCol] = board[outRow][outCol];
    board[outRow][outCol] = tmp;
}

void printBoard(char board[8][8]) {
    cout << "# a b c d e f g h " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        cout << 8 - i << " ";
        for(int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

bool isValidMoveRook(int inCol, int inRow, int outCol, int outRow, char board[8][8]) {
    int smallCol = min(inCol, outCol);
    int smallRow = min(inRow, outRow);
    int maxCol = max(inCol, outCol);
    int maxRow = max(inRow, outRow);
    if(inRow == outRow) {
        for(int i = smallCol + 1; i < maxCol; i++) {
            if(board[inRow][i] != '-') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if(outCol == inCol) {
        for(int i = smallRow + 1; i < maxRow; i++) {
            if(board[i][inCol] != '-') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
bool isValidMoveBishop(int inCol, int inRow, int outCol, int outRow, char board[8][8]) {
    int rowDiff = outRow - inRow;
    int colDiff = outCol - inCol;
    if(abs(outRow - inRow) == abs(outCol - inCol)) {
        if(rowDiff < 0 && colDiff < 0) {
            for(int i = 1; i > rowDiff; i--) {
                if(board[inRow + rowDiff][inCol + rowDiff] != '-') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        return true;
    }
}

bool isValidMove(int inCol, int inRow, int outCol, int outRow, char board[8][8]) {
    if(board[inRow][inCol] == '-') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if(board[inRow][inCol] == 'R' || board[inRow][inCol] == 'r' && isValidMoveRook(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board)) {
        return true;
        }   
    }
}


void movePiece(char board[8][8]) {
    string input;
    string output;
    cout << "Please enter your piece position : ";
    cin >> input;
    cout << "Please enter where you want to place your piece : ";
    cin >> output;

    int inCol = input[0] - 'a';
    int inRow = 7 - (input[1] - '1');
    int outCol = output[0] - 'a';
    int outRow = 7 - (output[1] - '1');
    while(!isValidMove(inCol, inRow, outCol, outRow, board)) {
        cout << "Invalid input try again" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter your piece position : ";
        cin >> input;
        cout << "Please enter where you want to place your piece : ";
        cin >> output;
        inCol = input[0] - 'a';
        inRow = 7 - (input[1] - '1');
        outCol = output[0] - 'a';
        outRow = 7 - (output[1] - '1');
    }
    if(board[outRow][outCol] == '-') {
        swap(board, inRow, inCol, outRow, outCol);
    }
    else {
        if(isupper(board[inRow][inCol]) != isupper(board[outRow][outCol])) {
            board[outRow][outCol] = board[inRow][inCol];
            board[inRow][inCol] = '-';
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printBoard(board);
    while (true) {
        movePiece(board);
        printBoard(board);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could at least tell as what line you get the error...

Comment: I edited it now

Comment: You are missing a `}` in the middle of `isValidMoveBishop`.

Comment: thank you for catching my mistake I will edit it now

Comment: If you have a code formatter, run the program through it to spot problems like this. The formatter will reach the missing brace and probably break the indentation afterward making the error easy to spot. Fix the error and then re-run the formatter to clean the code back up.

Comment: I don't have a formatter can you tell me where to get one

Comment: This error message can happen to both C and C++ programs. I will give an example that may help other programmers.  It took me more than 20 minutes to spot this one. Should help other programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `}` in `isValidMoveBishop`. Thus, the function's definition is not ended, and the compiler thinks you're trying to define another function **inside** it:

```
bool isValidMoveBishop(int inCol, int inRow, int outCol, int outRow, char board[8][8]) {
    int rowDiff = outRow - inRow;
    int colDiff = outCol - inCol;
    if(abs(outRow - inRow) == abs(outCol - inCol)) {
        if(rowDiff < 0 && colDiff < 0) {
            for(int i = 1; i > rowDiff; i--) {
                if(board[inRow + rowDiff][inCol + rowDiff] != '-') {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    } // This closing } was missing in the OP
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: With a pair of foo.h foo.c or foo.cpp, I copy-pasted the function definition to the header file: with proper include guard #ifndef BLABLA_H #define BLABLA_H "bool somefunction(Someobject* stack) {" #endif.  Forgot to polish the end. The compiler is firing numerous error message for every function definition in the foo.c file. Look for unpaired { in the header file in this situation.  Remove { add ; will fix this issue.